# How can I specify specific areas for clicking on ImageView?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a mobile application in Android studio, where the entire screen is occupied by a human image. The user should click, for example, on the leg, and information about the leg will be displayed to him. But I ran into the problem of specifying certain arbitrary places on the image, clicking on which a new activity will open. Tell me, please, how can this be implemented? There will be a lot of arbitrary "buttons" in the image. Here's my example using coordinates, but it's terribly inconvenient, maybe someone knows a better way?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView imageView;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.front_man);

    // Определение областей изображения
    Rect handRect = new Rect(100, 100, 200, 200);
    Rect legRect = new Rect(300, 300, 400, 400);

    // Обработка нажатия
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            // Проверка области нажатия
            if (handRect.contains((int) x, (int) y)) {
                // Переход на макет с описанием руки
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HandActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (legRect.contains((int) x, (int) y)) {
                // Переход на макет с описанием ноги
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LegActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}
}
```

I write code in Java, but you can also drop your tips on Kotlin)